# How does a router route an ip packet if two subnets are attached with different netmasks but same prefix

Tags: networking, routing, ip, router, netmask

Imagine we have 3 subnets attached to one router:

```
Host A: 192.168.1.1 Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Host B: 192.168.2.2 Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Host C: 192.168.2.3 Netmask: 255.255.0.0
```

If Host A sends an IP packet to the ip 192.168.2.3, how does the router knows to which network the ip belongs to? 192.168.2.3 could be a host of the network 192.168.0.0/16 or an host of 192.168.2.0/24. What happens if both networks have an host with equal ip addresses? e.g.: `Host C: 192.168.2.3/16` and `Host C: 192.168.2.3/24`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`What happens if both networks have an host with equal ip addresses?`

Longest Prefix Match

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_prefix_match

Comment: And in the first scenario? How does the router know to which network 192.168.2.3 belongs to?

Comment: @Sebi2020: same. There should be entries in the routing table for destination networks. The most specific/longest prefix match is selected.